# Operator does not exist Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I've created a trigger function to dynamically create tables, here it is:

```
declare 
   tipo smallint;
   tamanho smallint;
   nome character varying(100);
   cur_atri cursor for select atri_nome, atri_tipo, tamanho from atributo where colecao = new.col_id;
   colecao_nome text := 'marcacao_'||new.col_nome;
   query text;
begin

if new.col_aprovada is true and old.col_aprovada is false then
open cur_atri;

   query := 'create table '||colecao_nome||' (id serial not null, colecao integer not null references public.colecao (col_id), primary key (id))';
   execute query;

   loop
      fetch cur_atri into nome, tipo, tamanho;
      exit when not found;

      if tipo = 0 then query := 'alter table '||colecao_nome||' add column '||nome||' integer';
      elsif tipo = 1 then query := 'alter table '||colecao_nome||' add column '||nome||' character varying '||tamanho||;
      elsif tipo = 2 then query := 'alter table '||colecao_nome||' add column '||nome||' boolean';
      elsif tipo = 3 then query := 'alter table '||colecao_nome||' add column '||nome||' real';
      elsif tipo = 4 then query := 'alter table '||colecao_nome||' add column '||nome||' bytea';
      end if;

      execute query;
    end loop;
    close cur_atri;
end if;
end;
```

This error is shown on my website when the trigger is activated:

> Message: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: operator does not exist: text || LINE 1: ...me||' add column '|| nome ||' character varying '||tamanho|| ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. QUERY: SELECT 'alter table '||colecao_nome||' add column '|| nome ||' character varying '||tamanho|| CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function criar_tabela_colecao() line 21 at assignment

I really don't know what is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of such concatenation, try using format. smth like:

```
if tipo = 0 then query := format('alter table %I add column %I integer',colecao_nome,nome);
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT

> **I** treats the argument value as an **SQL identifier**, double-quoting it if
>   necessary. It is an error for the value to be null (equivalent to
>   quote_ident).

(formatting mine)

Comment: What '%I' stands for?

Comment: The error has changed, now its:

 Query failed: ERROR: null values cannot be formatted as an SQL identifier CONTEXT...

I guess some value there is null, but I don't know why

Comment: it's a different question - you should ask it as a new post. but in short - add `coalesce` to every of three columns you select in `cur_atri` and error will tell you where you had null. or just add `where (atri_nome, atri_tipo, tamanho) is not null` *as if one column of row is null the row itself is null*

Answer (score 0):

You have a dangling '||' on

```
elsif tipo = 1 then query := 'alter table '||colecao_nome||' add column '||nome||' character varying '||tamanho||;
```

so change it to

```
elsif tipo = 1 then query := 'alter table '||colecao_nome||' add column '||nome||' character varying '||tamanho;
```